# View of recarray as ndarray

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, numpy-ndarray

In previous versions of numpy, I was able to do something like this:

```
data = np.array([(0,1,2),(3,4,5),(6,7,8)], dtype=np.dtype([('a','<f8'), ('b','<f8'),('c','<f8')]))


data_nd = data[['a','b']].view(('<f8',2))
```

and this would give me a view of the original recarray `data` as a 2 dimensional ndarray of type `np.float32`.

In numpy version 1.14 when I try the second line above I get the error:

```
ValueError: Changing the dtype to a subarray type is only supported if the total itemsize is unchanged
```

This is because the itemsize of `data[['a','b']]` is still 24. Okay, that's fine, but is there some way to get a copy of those columns of data that updates the itemsize so that I can make the view that I want?

For instance, even making a copy (or deep copy) of `data[['a','b']]` still results in an itemsize of 24, which I don't understand.

Comment: I haven't fully digested the consequences of these 1.14 changes.  You may need to resort to a `tolist` intermediary, or to copying fields by name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you realize that without tuples your recarray is 3x3 with replicated field values:

```
In [46]: data
Out[46]: 
array([[(0., 0., 0.), (1., 1., 1.), (2., 2., 2.)],
       [(3., 3., 3.), (4., 4., 4.), (5., 5., 5.)],
       [(6., 6., 6.), (7., 7., 7.), (8., 8., 8.)]],
      dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('c', '<f8')])
```

Anyways, a view on the whole array still works, and you could use conventional column slicing on that:

```
In [47]: data.view(('float',(3,)))
Out[47]: 
array([[[0., 0., 0.],
        [1., 1., 1.],
        [2., 2., 2.]],

       [[3., 3., 3.],
        [4., 4., 4.],
        [5., 5., 5.]],

       [[6., 6., 6.],
        [7., 7., 7.],
        [8., 8., 8.]]])
In [48]: _.shape
Out[48]: (3, 3, 3)
```

`tolist` is the old standby for converting to/from structured arrays.  It still works:

```
In [49]: np.array(data[['a','b']].tolist())
Out[49]: 
array([[[0., 0.],
        [1., 1.],
        [2., 2.]],

       [[3., 3.],
        [4., 4.],
        [5., 5.]],

       [[6., 6.],
        [7., 7.],
        [8., 8.]]])
```

---

Changing the `data` creation to include tuples, doesn't actually change view behavior, but may be closer to what you want (or what I'd want anyways):

```
In [50]: data1 = np.array([(0,1,2),(3,4,5),(6,7,8)], dtype=np.dtype([('a','<f8')
    ...: , ('b','<f8'),('c','<f8')]))
In [51]: data1
Out[51]: 
array([(0., 1., 2.), (3., 4., 5.), (6., 7., 8.)],
      dtype=[('a', '<f8'), ('b', '<f8'), ('c', '<f8')])
```

Note that the subfield display now includes an offsets parameter.

```
In [53]: data1[['a','b']]
Out[53]: 
array([(0., 1.), (3., 4.), (6., 7.)],
      dtype={'names':['a','b'], 'formats':['<f8','<f8'], 'offsets':[0,8], 'itemsize':24})
```

The underlying database is the same, so a 3 column view works with and without the subfield indexing:

```
In [54]: data1[['a','b']].view((float,(3,)))
Out[54]: 
array([[0., 1., 2.],
       [3., 4., 5.],
       [6., 7., 8.]])
In [55]: data1.view((float,(3,)))
Out[55]: 
array([[0., 1., 2.],
       [3., 4., 5.],
       [6., 7., 8.]])
```

I haven't read up on the latest changes.  Instead I'm using various tricks that have worked in the past.  Converting to/from a structured array has never been simple and foolproof.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the lack of tuples. I did indeed want them and I've updated the original question to reflect that. I've settled on using a view of the whole array and just slicing it as you mentioned.